# How can I capture webcam view with Microsoft Movie Maker

Tags: windows-7, video, webcam, windows-movie-maker

I used to use Microsoft Movie Maker to record video from my webcam.

Now I have Win7 and just downloaded the [latest version of movie maker](http://download.live.com/) (14.0.8091.0730), the one that has the Office-10-like Ribbon on the top.

But in this version I find no way to capture video as in the [older versions](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/email/video/windows-movie-maker.html).

**How can I capture video from my webcam with this newest version of Movie Maker?**

Comment: i think it's called 'progress' :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I capture video from my webcam
>   with this newest version of Movie
>   Maker?

you can't, but this one's still got all the goodies:

> Windows Movie Maker is a free
>   Microsoft utility for Windows that
>   lets you create and edit video files.
>   But for some reason, the most recent
>   versions of Movie Maker for Windows
>   Vista and 7 don't have all the
>   features and transitions you can find
>   on earlier builds.
>
> So one developer decided to take
>   matters into his own hands and create
>   a [portable version of Windows Movie
>   Maker based on Movie Maker 2.1](http://devrexster.googlepages.com/mmk).
>   You can run Portable Windows Movie
>   Maker on any computer with Windows XP,
>   Vista, or 7. And since it's portable,
>   you can run it from a USB flash drive
>   or a folder on your hard drive without
>   installing it.